Is this the expected output of .replace() or is it bug?
This code:


const source = `'$' apple, orange`
const replaceFrom = `'$' apple`
const replaceTo = `'$' peach`
const result = source.replace(replaceFrom, replaceTo)

console.log('\nSource:\n', source)
console.log('\nReplaceFrom:\n', replaceFrom)
console.log('\nReplaceTo:\n', replaceTo)
console.log('\nResult:\n', result)



produces this output:
Source:
 '$' apple, orange

ReplaceFrom:
 '$' apple

ReplaceTo:
 '$' peach

Result:
 ', orange peach, orange


Is this the expected output of .replace() in JavaScript, or is it some sort of bug?
If this behavior is expected, how can we reliably replace arbitrary strings with other arbitrary strings in JavaScript?

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_the_replacement - it's $' that's the problem here, you want "'$$' peach" for a literal dollar sign.

Solution is to use a getter function, like const result = source.replace(replaceFrom, () => replaceTo) then $' is not treated as a special character
